# Possible bug in breeze

Tags: breeze

I think I found a bug.

What I am doing is the following:

1. I create a new entity and add the entity to the manager.

   ```
   var createConexion = function (origen, destino) {
       var metadataStore = manager.metadataStore;
       var conexionType = metadataStore.getEntityType("ConexionPalanca");
       var newConexion = conexionType.createEntity();

       newConexion.PalancaDestinoID(destino.PalancaID());
       newConexion.PalancaOrigenID(origen.PalancaID());
       newConexion.Activa(true);

       manager.addEntity(newConexion);

       return newConexion;
   };
   ```
2. Cancel the changes.

   ```
   var cancelChanges = function () {
       return manager.rejectChanges();
   };
   ```
3. I run a local query.

   ```
       var getConexiones = function () {
           var query = EntityQuery.from("ConexionesPalancas");
           return manager.executeQueryLocally(query);
       };
   ```

Performing these steps I get the following error when executeQueryLocally is called:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Can not read property 'entityAspect' of null at line 9249 (breeze.js)
```

I'm using breeze 0.74.2

Edit: This is the model i'm using:

```
public class Palanca {
    public int PalancaID { get; set; }
    /*More properties ommited*/
    public virtual ICollection<ConexionPalanca> ConexionesSalientes { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ConexionPalanca> ConexionesEntrantes { get; set; }
}

public class ConexionPalanca {
    public int PalancaOrigenID { get; set; }
    public virtual Palanca PalancaOrigen { get; set; }

    public int PalancaDestinoID { get; set; }
    public virtual Palanca PalancaDestino { get; set; }
    public string Anchor { get; set; }
}

public class PalancaConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Palanca> {
    public PalancaConfiguration() : base() {
    HasKey( p => p.PalancaID );
    Property( p => p.PalancaID )
            .IsRequired()
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    HasMany( p => p.ConexionesSalientes ).WithRequired( cp => cp.PalancaOrigen).HasForeignKey(cp=>cp.PalancaOrigenID);
    HasMany( p => p.ConexionesEntrantes ).WithRequired( cp => cp.PalancaDestino).HasForeignKey( cp => cp.PalancaDestinoID ).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}

public class ConexionPalancaConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ConexionPalanca> {
    public ConexionPalancaConfiguration() {
        HasKey( cp => new {cp.PalancaOrigenID, cp.PalancaDestinoID} );

        HasRequired( cp => cp.PalancaOrigen ).WithMany( p => p.ConexionesSalientes ).HasForeignKey( cp => cp.PalancaOrigenID );
        HasRequired( cp => cp.PalancaDestino ).WithMany(p=>p.ConexionesEntrantes).HasForeignKey( cp => cp.PalancaDestinoID );
    }
}
```

Comment: I have confirmed the bug and we are tracking it. I predict we'll have it fixed by end of week (we're a bit short handed this week).

Comment: Ok, Thx. Can you post this comment as an answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug.  It has been fixed in v 0.74.3 and is available via the breeze website or thru nuget. Please let us know if this corrects the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I ecnountered a similar error. It turned out the bug was on my side. It seems you are setting up a connection table. Make sure your Models are properly configured with foreignKey Attribute (or fluent API). 
Why are you setting the ID yourself in the first place, should it not be like this and let breeze handle it?

```
newConexion.PalancaDestinoID(destino); <---
newConexion.PalancaOrigenID(origen);   <---
newConexion.Activa(true);
```

The following works well:

```
createTeamUser = function (user, team, temporary) {
            var teamUserType = metadataStore.getEntityType("TeamUsers");
            var newTeamUser = teamUserType.createEntity();
            newTeamTemp = manager.addEntity(newTeamUser);
            newTeamUser.Team(team);
            newTeamUser.User(user);



            user.TeamUsers().push(newTeamTemp); 
            team.TeamUsers().push(newTeamTemp);
            return newTeamTemp;
        },
```

with this model:

```
public class TeamUsers
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long TeamUsersId { get; set; }

    public long TeamId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TeamId")]
    [InverseProperty("TeamUsers")]
    public Team Team { get; set; }

    public long UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]            //<---- Withour these attributes i got a null error too 
    [InverseProperty("TeamUsers")]    //<---- 
    public User User { get; set; }

    public bool Temporary { get; set; }

    //[Timestamp]
    //public byte[] TimeStamp { get; set; }
}
```

with this field in the `User` model:

```
 [InverseProperty("User")]
    public ICollection<TeamUsers> TeamUsers { get; set; }
```

Question: Julianyus adds the navigation properties before adding the new entity to the manager. He is setting attributes on the `detached` entity. As far as i understood the breeze-Docs everything done with the entity should be after adding it to the manager/cash. Is it safe to use the entity before adding to cache or not?

Comment: I added the navigation properties before adding the entity to the manager because they are the primary key.

Comment: Reading the documentation, I understand that the result is the same assigning the navigation property or assigning the foreign key (as in entity framework)

Comment: It's a real bug. See my comment on the question itself